# Already installed PyAudio but "Could not find PyAudio" is prompted when try to use Speech_recognition module (Mac M1)

Tags: pip, homebrew, apple-m1, pyaudio, portaudio

Almost all the solutions in stack overflow are tested but still can not run the following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print("Listening...")
     r.pause_threshold = 1
     audio = r.listen(source)
```

Mainly, the error prompted is:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
  File "/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sadra/Desktop/Project/irandoc/mirror/sr.py", line 3, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Also, when I try to `import pyaudio` alone, the error is:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sadra/Desktop/Project/irandoc/mirror/sr.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sadra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'
```

I tried different solutions, installed portAudio and PyAudio in many ways but, still the problem is remained.

Answer (score 0):

After testing different approaches, the final solution was much more simple than the prescriptions recommended in stack overflow and it was just installing the earlier version of PyAudio (currently, the latest version is 0.2.13 and I installed 0.2.12 instead) and surprisingly it works!

`pip install pyaudio==0.2.12`