# "Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'." due to "symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'"(Mac M1 Chip)

Tags: python, python-3.x, apple-m1, pyaudio, portaudio

I tried to pip install pyaudio on my Macbook pro M1 Chip version. I was be able to install both `portaudio` and `pyaudio`  successfully and then when I import pyaudio, I met an import error as below

```
(test) oldman@oldman-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 
Python 3.8.8 (v3.8.8:024d8058b0, Feb 19 2021, 08:48:17) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio 
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/oldman/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/oldman/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'
```

The issue is similar to the one in [Import pyaudio doesn't work - Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap on mac (Big Sur M1 Apple Silicon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709212/import-pyaudio-doesnt-work-symbol-not-found-pamaccore-setupchannelmap-on-ma). I tried all the solutions provided under that issue, but none of them works. I am wondering if anyone have the similar issue and I am not sure what goes wrong as the latest solution they provided is in 2022. Not sure if anything change during this time. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For me it was fixing the version to pyaudio==0.2.12 as suggested [here]( https://stackoverflow.com/a/76404424) what worked. For you, too?